# How to import SQL database from PC to Android app

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm working on Android app which will use SQL database. I created the database with data on my PC. I have SQL dump file for this database. I would like to use this dump file to create and use SQLite database as a part of the app. How could I achieve this? I will appreciate the hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that dump file from SQLite or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sql file on your PC then just drag and drop it in a folder in Android Studio let it be under /Database. Then you can use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can Converts your MySQL dump to SQLite3 compatible dump using this link as . You must have git and GitHub installed on your computer . please use this link [Sql to SQLite](https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite)
Worked fine for me , Good Luck